# saxon cli vs oxygen discrepancy

Tags: xslt, saxon

I am trying to transform xml to html.  With oxygen the Xpath such as follows:

```
<a href="#cite{count(preceding::citation) + 1}">
    <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding::citation) + 1"/>
</a>
```

Basically the purpose of this is to insert a numbered reference link, based on count of references preceeding.

This works when transformed in oxygen.

When run from command line, `1` is the output for all links.

command line commands Ive attempted look like this:

```
java  -jar /usr/share/java/saxon9he.jar -s:report1.xml -xsl:test.xsl -o:output4.html -t
```

I have also tried saxon9ee:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/saxon9ee.jar com.saxonica.Transform -s:report1.xml -xsl:test.xsl -o:output3.html -t
```

Any help is appreciated!

test.xsl can be found here
http://pastebin.com/6qZeEgD8 
report1.xml 
http://pastebin.com/5SMY8c7W

contentconfig.xml 
http://pastebin.com/A2etm4Cr

Here is the `-t` output:

```
 Saxon-HE 9.7.0.4J from Saxonica
 Java version 1.7.0_79
 Stylesheet compilation time:    1.59928s (1599.280903ms)
 Processing file:/root /CRIReportProject/cpreport.xml
 Using parser  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
 Building tree for file:/root/CRIReportProject/cpreport.xml using   class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
 Tree built in 1.296529ms
 Tree size: 27 nodes, 54 characters, 5 attributes
 URIResolver.resolve href="contentconfig.xml" base="file:/root/CRIReportProject/cptest.xsl"
 Building tree for file:/root/CRIReportProject/contentconfig.xml using class net.sf.saxon.tree.tiny.TinyBuilder
 Tree built in 3.144498ms
 Tree size: 28 nodes, 161 characters, 6 attributes
 Execution time: 131.347609ms
```

Memory used: 8428592

Comment: Could be a namespace issue, Saxon's far more likely to be handling that correctly. Does your source have any namespace declaration that your `citation` element might belong to?

Comment: Can you post minimal but complete samples to allow us to reproduce the problem? Which version of Saxon 9 is that exactly, what does `-t` show?

Comment: Also, research the `xsl:number` instruction. Difficult to say for sure, but it might be helpful as an alternative to counting preceding nodes, which isn't particularly efficient for large documents.

Comment: In future please post your code in the body of the question, not on an external site. Such links tend to go dead, leaving an orphaned question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are executing `count(preceding::citation)` in the template rule with match="method", and the context item for the evaluation is a `<method>` element in document `report1.xml`. This document contains no `<citation>` elements, so it is entirely reasonable that `count(preceding::citation)` should return zero. Your surrounding `<xsl:if>` takes a look in the other document `contentconfig.xml`, but it doesn't change the context to that document. Perhaps the `xsl:if` should be changed to an `xsl:for-each`, but then you need to make other changes as well, because the code is also looking for elements such as `sup/a/@id` which don't exist in either source document.

I have no idea why this code should behave differently in oXygen.

And by the way, if you do change the xsl:if to xsl:for-each, then you can probably change `count(preceding::citation)+1` to `position()`, which will be much more efficient.

Comment: reason it appeared to work in oxygenXML is that the contentconfig.xml file was linked to the transform not the report1.xml...